# JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY - Filtering option(Selecting 1 value from dropdown)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Condition:

Say suppose I've few values listed in alphabetical order starting with 'A' alphabet & then with 'B' and then 'C' so on....

If I select alphabet 'A' and it will display values stating with 'A'...in that I'll select few rows listed by 'A' using check box. Now if select Alphabet B and I'll select few rows listed by 'B' using check box and the same with other alphabets as well...

Here is my requirement below:

1) If I go back to any alphabet filter then the selected checkbox rows should be displayed as selected..I mean they should not get deselected even if I navigate among filters back and forth.

2) Also If I select all in the filters then the check boxes that I've selected earlier individually for each Alphabet should be displayed. They should not get deselected.

Please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a question or a freelance assignment?

Comment: It is a question Rob...I'm unable to find a solution for this requirement.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I'm not supposed to share code as it is COD voilation

Comment: I added a second set with the same setup, only with a display:none; on the tab navigation UL, so the only navigation through the divs is using the select element. Again, the checkboxes maintain state just fine.

Comment: Thanks Rob...Let me try this tomorrow.This is not a school assignment, this requirement is at my work place.

Comment: We have a ticketing tool and we have a requirement where we need to customize that tool....for one of the requirement, where I need to segregate different tickets based on the subject line and display them separately in different tabs based on status.....I cannot put all those details over here. So I've taken a generalized scenario to ask a question in this forum, and if I get any inputs....I can apply them over there in work place....Could you please provide me the code that you have used to display this output

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Testing Page</title>
<meta name="description" content="File to generate strong passwords of a chosen length.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-old-ie-min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->

<style>



</style>

</head>

<body style="font-size:11px;">

<div id="tabs" style="margin:24px;margin-top:48px;">
  <form class="pure-form">
    <select id="alpha" style="float:right;margin-top:4px;margin-right:8px;width:60px;">

    <?php

    for($i=65;$i<91;$i++) {

    ?>

    <option value="<?= chr($i); ?>"><?= chr($i); ?></option>

    <?php 

    }

    ?>

    </select>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <?php

    for($i=65;$i<91;$i++) {

    ?>

    <li><a href="#tabs-<?= chr($i); ?>" id="tablink-<?= chr($i); ?>"><?= chr($i); ?></a></li>

    <?php 

    }

    ?>
  </ul>
    <?php

    for($i=65;$i<91;$i++) {

    ?>

    <div id="tabs-<?= chr($i); ?>">
      <?php
      for($j=65;$j<91;$j++) {
      ?>
      <span style="margin-right:12px;border:1px solid #dedede;padding:4px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-<?= chr($i); ?><?= chr($j); ?>" id="checkbox-<?= chr($i); ?><?= chr($j); ?>"> <?= chr($i); ?>-<?= chr($j); ?></span>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </div>

    <?php 

    }

    ?>
</div>

<div id="tabs2" style="margin:24px;margin-top:48px;">
  <form class="pure-form">
    <select id="alpha2" style="float:right;margin-top:4px;margin-right:8px;width:60px;">

    <?php

    for($i=65;$i<91;$i++) {

    ?>

    <option value="<?= chr($i); ?>"><?= chr($i); ?></option>

    <?php 

    }

    ?>

    </select>
  </form>
  <ul style="display:none;">
    <?php

    for($i=65;$i<91;$i++) {

    ?>

    <li><a href="#tabs2-<?= chr($i); ?>" id="tablink2-<?= chr($i); ?>"><?= chr($i); ?></a></li>

    <?php 

    }

    ?>
  </ul>
    <?php

    for($i=65;$i<91;$i++) {

    ?>

    <div id="tabs2-<?= chr($i); ?>">
      <?php
      for($j=65;$j<91;$j++) {
      ?>
      <span style="margin-right:12px;border:1px solid #dedede;padding:4px;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2-<?= chr($i); ?><?= chr($j); ?>" id="checkbox2-<?= chr($i); ?><?= chr($j); ?>"> <?= chr($i); ?>-<?= chr($j); ?></span>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </div>

    <?php 

    }

    ?>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>

$( function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  $( "#tabs2" ).tabs();
} );

$('#alpha').on('change',function(){

  $('#tablink-' + $(this).val()).trigger('click');

});

$('#alpha2').on('change',function(){

  $('#tablink2-' + $(this).val()).trigger('click');

});





</script>

</body>
</html>
```